# How to disable window scrollbar and page scrolling when dialog opened?

Tags: jquery

I have made a dialog popup using Jquery UI, and I want to disable window scroll bar and disable page scrolling when dialog opened.

So i tried this code

```
$('.btnContact').click(function() {
     $('.layerContact').dialog('open');
     $('body').addClass('stop-scrolling');
});  



.stop-scrolling {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

It works fine on PC browser. 
But the problem is it does not working on Mobile.

What do I have to fix the code ?

please Help~

Comment: do not need to add new class. and if you already assign new class then no need to define height property.

Answer (score 0):

You have add two css property when model window open at that time add **`$('body').css('overflow','hidden')`**.

And another one when you close the model window add assign **`$('body').css('overflow','scroll')`** overflow property value to archive your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code when dialogue is opened to stop the scroll

```
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

Add this to enable that again

```
$("body").css("overflow", "auto");
```